# "go get" authentication problem on cloud.google.com

Tags: git, go, google-cloud-platform

whenever I try to install a package from cloud.google.com on a Windows machine in GO it results in the following eror:

```
go get -u cloud.google.com/go/translate
# cd C:\Users\******\go\src\google.golang.org\genproto; git pull --ff-only
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
package google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status: exit status 1
```

I tried to setup an SSH key as stated here: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/authentication#ssh and I also installed the cloud SDK. However nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Can you clarify by "tried to setup SSH key" ? What happend then ? 
Any error messages etc ? Please provide more details to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I can `git clone https://google.golang.org/genproto/` just fine on my machine, without any credentials. Check if you can do it too on your machine.

Comment: It's a Compute Engine with windows installed on it? if so, do you use special feature? Special firewall rules? Cloud NAT?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I was sick the last days.
git clone https://google.golang.org/genproto/  does not work either-> fatal: repository 'https://google.golang.org/genproto/' not found  

Thats very strange

Comment: Can you provide more detail on your OS and Go version ? Are you still unable to install the package ? what other packeges have you tried to install ? Please provide as much detail as possible to make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: I am using windows 10 with go version 1.15.1 - however the same thing happens on my mac.
I am able to clone the required repositories and I just copy them to "GOPATH/src/" which solves my problem for now.
The problem persists only for "cloud.google.com/go..." packages. For example "go get neurosnap/sentences.v1" works without any problems ;-)

Comment: Can you give some repositories examples that work and some that don't ?